# Swift & UIView : How do we add an action to UIView via an extension?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, extension-methods

I can't add an action to my `UIView` when implementing in UIView `Extension`.

UIView Extension

```
extension UIView {
public func addAction(_ selector: Selector) {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

In function in ViewController

```
func setAction(_ button: UIView, _ selector: Selector?) {
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selector)
        button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }

@objc func hello(){
  print("Hello")
}
```

I have a UIView Controller called menu, and I want it to print out "Hello" when I press on it.

If I do method 1, I will get an error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView hello:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11fd4ca30'
```

if I do method 2, it works just fine.

1 - `menu.addAction(#selector(hello))`

2 - `setAction(menu, #selector(hello))`

But I might be using this very often. How do we add an action to UIView via an extension?

Answer (score 1):

in extension tapgesture not found `hello` method in `UIView` class.

```
extension UIView {
public func addAction(_ selector: Selector, target: AnyObject) {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: selector)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
}
```

add one parameter in `addAction` method for target of action.